# TypeError: database.insert is not a function occurs in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, rest

Up, running and ready for action!
When GET method is used, the below output comes but never completes loading... from POSTMAN Why?

```
Successfully connected to MongoDB instance!
MongoDB returned the following documents:

[ { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] },
    name: 'Apple',
    price: 2.5 },
  { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] },
    name: 'Pear',
    price: 3 },
  { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] },
    name: 'Orange',
    price: 3 } ]
```

When POST method is used, the below error occurred. Why?

```
/Users/json/Dev/restful_api/api.js:21
  database.insert('OrderBase', resourceName, resource, function(err, resource) {
           ^
TypeError: database.insert is not a function
    at insertResource (/Users/json/Dev/restful_api/api.js:21:12)
    at insertProduct (/Users/json/Dev/restful_api/api.js:34:3)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/json/Dev/restful_api/api.js:66:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Can anyone explain? I am new to NodeJs. Thanks a lot!

```
var http = require('http');
var database = require('./database');
var url = require('url');


// Generic find methods (GET)
function findAllResources(resourceName, req, res) {
  database.find('OrderBase', resourceName, {}, function (err, resources) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(resources));
  });
};
var findResourceById = function (resourceName, id, req, res) {
  database.find('OrderBase', resourceName, {'_id': id}, function(err, resource) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(resource));
  });
};
// Generic insert/update methods (POST, PUT)
var insertResource = function (resourceName, resource, req, res) {
  database.insert('OrderBase', resourceName, resource, function(err, resource) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(resource));
  });
};
// Product methods
var findAllProducts = function (req, res) {
  findAllResources('Products', req, res);
};
var findProductById = function (id, req, res) {
  findResourceById('Products', id, req, res);
};
var insertProduct = function (product, req, res) {
  insertResource('OrderBase', 'Product', product, function (err, result) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
};

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
// Break down the incoming URL into its components
  var parsedURL = url.parse(req.url, true);
// Determine a response based on the URL
  switch (parsedURL.pathname) {
    case '/api/products':
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
    // Find and return the product with the given id
      if (parsedURL.query.id) {
        findProductById(id, req, res);
      }
      // There is no id specified, return all products
      else {
        findAllProducts(req, res);
      }
    }
    else if (req.method === 'POST') {
      //Extract the data stored in the POST body
      var body = '';
      req.on('data', function (dataChunk) {
        body += dataChunk;
      });
      req.on('end', function () {
        // Done pulling data from the POST body.
        // Turn it into JSON and proceed to store it in the database.
        var postJSON = JSON.parse(body);
        insertProduct(postJSON, req, res);
      });
    }
    break;
    default:
    res.end('You shall not pass!');
  }
});

server.listen(8080);
console.log('Up, running and ready for action!');
```

database file

```
// Our primary interface for the MongoDB instance
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
// Used in order to verify correct return values
var assert = require('assert');
/**
*
* @param databaseName - name of the database we are connecting to
* @param callBack - callback to execute when connection finishes
*/
var connect = function (databaseName, callback) {
// URL to the MongoDB instance we are connecting to
  var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/' + databaseName;
// Connect to our MongoDB instance, retrieve the selected
// database, and execute a callback on it.
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (error, database) {
// Make sure that no error was thrown
    assert.equal(null, error);
    console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB instance!");
    callback(database);
  });
};
/**
* Executes the find() method of the target collection in the
* target database, optionally with a query.
* @param databaseName - name of the database
* @param collectionName - name of the collection
* @param query - optional query parameters for find()
*/
exports.find = function (databaseName, collectionName, query) {
  connect(databaseName, function (database) {
    // The collection we want to find documents from
    var collection = database.collection(collectionName);
    // Search the given collection in the given database for
    // all documents which match the criteria, convert them to
    // an array, and finally execute a callback on them.
    collection.find(query).toArray(
      // Callback method
      function (err, documents) {
        // Make sure nothing went wrong
        assert.equal(err, null);
        // Print all the documents that we found, if any
        console.log("MongoDB returned the following documents:");
        console.dir(documents);
        // Close the database connection to free resources
        database.close();
      })
  })
};
```

Comment: what's in the imported database file. show it

Comment: database file added

Comment: it's simple you have defined the insert function